# Gitlab gems installation issue

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, package-managers

> on installation of Gitlab everything is fine but while installing gems
>   , it shows an error

```
 :/home/git/gitlab# sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.9.4'

    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Successfully installed charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4
    1 gem installed
    Installing ri documentation for charlock_holmes-0.6.9.4...
    unable to convert "\xE0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/i686-linux/charlock_holmes/charlock_holmes.so, skipping
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
        undefined method `map' for Gem::Specification:Class
```

Comment: Your gem installation was successful. The error is while generating docs, it should not affect your application.

Comment: Unable to login  gitlab at my local machine(ubuntu 12.04) http://imgur.com/fGqXCoe   and I am using  [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gitlab-as-your-very-own-private-github-clone) to install gitlab